# Jquery datatables fixed columns issue in IE 9

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-9, datatables

I am using **jquery ui tabs** to display two grids side by side within same div. Grid are displayed using **jquery datatables** plugin.
Recently i have added the feature of **fixed columns** in both of my grids, that makes IE 9 behave weirdly at random.

This behavior happen at total random but on one of the two grids not on both. **IE 9 display fixed column portion over the horizontal scroll-bar**.  It looks like below:


[image]


Other grid display just fine like below:

[image]

Funny thing is if you **sort out** the affected table or **enter some characters in search textbox**, this overlapping portion got fixed automatically.

I search on it and came to know that **draw()** function is called on these actions so i tried to call this function manually on **tab selection event** but that **didn't solve the problem**.

Below is the JS code for tab selection event:

```
$('#divEAMountDismountGridsTabs, #CurrentSpec').tabs(
    {
        select: function(event, ui)
        {
            // Do stuff here
            var tempDismount = $('#tblDismountAtt').DataTable();
            tempDismount.draw(false);

            var tempCurrentSpec = $('#tblCurrentSpec1').DataTable();
            tempCurrentSpec.draw(false);
        }
    });
```

Below is the JS i write on **datatable initialization**(both grids got the same attributes so i am just copying the initialization of first grid).

```
/*DataTable Implementation*/
    var tableDismountAtt = $('#tblDismountAtt').dataTable(
    {
        "bFilter": true,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bwidth": '100%',
        //"sDom": '<"top"f>',
        'iDisplayLength':5000,
        "order": [[2, "asc"]],
         dom: "Cfrtip",
         scrollY: "140px",
         scrollX: "100%",
         paging: false,
         scrollCollapse: true,
        "aoColumnDefs" : [
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 0 ] , "width": "80px"}, //Switch to Dismount
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 1 ], "width": "80px"}, //Parts Status
                        {'bSortable' : true, 'aTargets' : [ 2 ], "width": "80px"}, //Sales Code
                        {'bSortable' : true, 'aTargets' : [ 3 ] , "width": "60px"}, //Price
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 4 ], "width": "60px"}, //Currency
                        {'bSortable' : true, 'aTargets' : [ 5 ], "width": "150px"}, //Sales Code Description
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 6 ], "width": "80px"}, //Quantity
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 7 ], "width": "380px"}, //Remarks
                        {'bSortable' : true, 'aTargets' : [ 8 ], "width": "80px"}, //    PSO Ref No.
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 9 ], "width": "150px"}, //Model Sub Name
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 10 ] , "width": "80px"}, //Value
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 11 ], "width": "150px"}, //Date
                        {'bSortable' : true, 'aTargets' : [ 12 ]},
                        {'bSortable' : true, 'aTargets' : [ 13 ]},
                        {'bSortable' : true, 'aTargets' : [ 14 ]}
                    ]

    });
    /*Freezing Dismount Attachment Columns*/       
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( tableDismountAtt, {leftColumns: 6, heightMatch: 'auto'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause of the problem was **initialization of second grid was occuring when it was hidden**, as a result when it became visible, alignment of controls got disturbed. This thing also mentioned on **JQuery Datatables** official site. You can read all the details from [here](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html).

To avoid this situation you need to call **AdjustColumns** function whenever the grid **shows/drawn**.

I have called this function two times:

1. When datatable initializes
2. When draw function called on grid

*(At first i only called this function on initialization, but when i tried to filter records using its smart search, alignment was getting disturbed again.)*

Below are the changes i have made to my datatable initialization code that is working fine now.

```
/*DataTable Implementation*/
    var tableDismountAtt = $('#tblDismountAtt').dataTable(
    {
        "bFilter": true,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bwidth": '100%',
        //"sDom": '<"top"f>',
        'iDisplayLength':5000,
        "order": [[2, "asc"]],
         dom: "Cfrtip",
         scrollY: "140px",
         scrollX: "100%",
         paging: false,
         scrollCollapse: true,
         "fnInitComplete": function () 
         {
            this.fnAdjustColumnSizing(true);
         },
         "fnDrawCallback" : function(oSettings)
         {
            this.fnAdjustColumnSizing(false);
         },
        "aoColumnDefs" : [
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 0 ] , "width": "80px"}, //Switch to Dismount
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 1 ], "width": "80px"}, //Parts Status
                        {'bSortable' : true, 'aTargets' : [ 2 ], "width": "80px"}, //Sales Code
                        {'bSortable' : true, 'aTargets' : [ 3 ] , "width": "60px"}, //Price
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 4 ], "width": "60px"}, //Currency
                        {'bSortable' : true, 'aTargets' : [ 5 ], "width": "150px"}, //Sales Code Description
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 6 ], "width": "80px"}, //Quantity
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 7 ], "width": "380px"}, //Remarks
                        {'bSortable' : true, 'aTargets' : [ 8 ], "width": "80px"}, //    PSO Ref No.
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 9 ], "width": "150px"}, //Model Sub Name
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 10 ] , "width": "80px"}, //Value
                        {'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 11 ], "width": "150px"}, //Date
                        {'bSortable' : true, 'aTargets' : [ 12 ]},
                        {'bSortable' : true, 'aTargets' : [ 13 ]},
                        {'bSortable' : true, 'aTargets' : [ 14 ]}
                    ]

    });
```

**Note:**

1. fnAdjustColumnSizing(true) => Adjust column size for all grids/datatables either they are visible or hidden.
2. fnAdjustColumnSizing(false) => Adjust column size for only grids/datatables those are visible.